# Ajax request vs Persist connection

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, performance, http

We are developing a sport live score website. From performance view which of these options are better?

1- Clients send ajax request every 1-2 seconds to server for live plays and their scores.

2- Using a persist connection library like WebSokcet or Laravel Broadcasting (or anything if better) and push any events to all clients?

Comment: `WebSokcet` are good.

Comment: @urfusion thanks for reply. Does WebSocket supports in all browsers? In large amount of clients, how can I estimate amount of ram/cpu usage when socket is used versus first option?

Answer (score 0):

Push notification is much better but as my previous experience you should pay more attention to one critical point and make a decision first:

- for push notification you need for client acceptance and if he decline you will not be able to send them anything.
  It means your application is affiliated to your clients choice and I think it's not the result that you expect.